# `var(A)` and order of execution

Tags: list, prolog, prolog-dif, logical-purity

Exercise 09 on this page http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/ asks to create a predicate that packs repeated elements into sublists.

A straightforward solution is straightforward

```
pack([], []).
pack([H|T], [I|U]) :-
    split(H, T, I, P),
    pack(P, U).
```

where split is `split(Head, Tail, HeadGroup, Rest)` is defined as

```
split(A, [], [A], []).
split(A, [B|T], [A], [B|T]) :- A \= B.
split(A, [A|T], [A|U], B) :- split(A, T, U, B).
```

which works fine and is pretty much in line with the example solution provided on the above-mentioned webpage.

Where this solution fails are the queries like `pack(X, [[a], [b, b]]).`. The correspondence between two solution sets is bijective (for every `A` in `pack(A, B)` there is one and only one `B`), so there must be a better solution.

One way to resolve it is to change the order of evaluation, helping prolog to pick non infinite branch depending on type of the argument like following

```
pack([], []).
pack(A, B) :-
  ( var(A) ->
    A = [H|T],
    B = [I|U],
    pack(P, U),
    split(H, T, I, P)
  ; A = [H|T],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    B = [I|U],
    split(H, T, I, P),
    pack(P, U)
  ).
```

Two questions in this regard.

Firstly, this is unbelievably ugly, so is there maybe a better way to pick order of rules depending on argument type?

Secondly, probably much more complex question, is there a way to rewrite the solution without `var(A)`, and if not why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a declarative point of view, non-monotonic constructs like `var/1` and `(\=)/2` are very **problematic**.

Why? Check it out:

```
?- var(A), A=a.
A = a.

?- A=a, var(A).
false.
```

So, this breaks **commutativity** of conjunction, which is one of the core properties we rely on when actually *reasoning* about logic programs.

What about `(\=)/2`, which you *thought* would express that two terms are different? Check it out:

```
?- X \= Y.
false.
```

**No two terms that are different exist**, yes? *Seems a bit strange to me*, to say the least, so apparently the predicate really means something else.

Luckily, in your case, the solution is *very easy*. Simply use the pure constraint `dif/2` to denote that two terms are *different*. See **[prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif)** for more information. You only have to change a single line of code to make your solution much more general. Instead of:

```
split(A, [B|T], [A], [B|T]) :- A \= B.
```

simply use `dif/2`:

```
split(A, [B|T], [A], [B|T]) :- dif(A, B).
```

With this change, your example works completely as expected:

```
?- pack(X, [[a], [b, b]]).
X = [a, b, b] ;
false.
```

Note that the existing Prolog literature is way **outdated**, and most such sets of solutions come from a time where `dif/2` was not even available in most Prolog systems, certainly not in free ones.

Comment: Pure genius! With `dif` it now can even solve the crazy stuff like `pack(A, [X, [b]]).`.

Comment: Gonna revisit all my previous solutions.

Comment: Yes, it is. `dif/2` was available even in the very first Prolog system, then by and large ignored by implementors, and now is getting increasingly common in implementations again. Reasoning in all directions is, after all, one of the major attractions of relational programming, so use `dif/2` to express term disequality in a sound and general way.